# 2002 Dodge Ram 1500 4.7L V8 Magnum Oil Change Capacity vs Dipstick Reading

Tags: oil, dodge, oil-change, ram, dipstick

Just done a oil change on my ram last night. Everywhere I've checked shows the capacity on the 2002 Ram 1500 4.7l is 6 quarts of 5w30 oil so that's exactly how much I put in. And I let the old oil drain for around half hour too.

I didn't drive it much yet to break the new oil in, I just moved the truck from the garage to the street last night after the change. But this morning I checked the dipstick and the level reads about 1/4 inch above the max fill line..

Any thoughts on this? I know for a fact I put pretty much exactly 6 quarts in it.

Comment: The dipstick didn't seem perfectly straight to me (pretty long dipstick with some curves along it over the years of previous owners/mechanics checking level).. Not sure if that would be enough to mess with the reading.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

So did you change the filter?

If you did not then the amount you put in would be over by the volume of the filter.

We always used to fill to stated amount less a pint and re-check and top up as needed.

Other possibility is that the sump has been dented or even replaced at some time…

That way we did not have the hassle of trying to remove 1/2 pint…

Comment: Hey Mike, first I drained all the old oil, then I unscrewed the old oil filter and let that drain, then I installed the new oil filter and filled the oil.

Comment: @Tj95 did you fill with 1/2 pint less ? If you did not, then you know for next time.

Comment: I just filled the full 6 quarts. Should I unscrew the new filter and drain it that way or will more than 1/2 pint come out?

Comment: @Tj95 - If you are absolutely positive it is over filled, it wouldn't be a bad way of doing it. You could also pop the oil plug for a second or so, letting some oil drain into a pan, put the plug back in and check the dipstick.